# What is "ANGLE" in an ArcGIS.com ADDRESS_POINTS table?

Tags: fields-attributes, arcgis-online, address, angles

Starting at e.g.,

https://gisdata-dupage.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/address-points/explore

how does the user find what the

- ANGLE (type: esriFieldTypeDouble, ...)

field represents? Angle measured from where to where? From the county courthouse to the current point?

I mean shouldn't there be some link somewhere where that is mentioned?

Exploring the points on the map, when a road goes from north-south to being east-west, the `angle` of the houses on the bend part seem to change with the bend. So maybe it is a property/building orientation field?

Comment: normally for text placement.

Answer (score 0):

Guess 1:

It is "how to calculate the angular position and layout direction for labels on or around point feature symbols."

https://developers.arcgis.com/net/api-reference/api/netwin/Esri.ArcGISRuntime/Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Mapping.LabelDefinition.Angle.html